# Allocating large memory and freeing up would purge unused memory (macos/java-android/windows)

Tags: android, windows, macos, operating-system

There are a lot of apps which are titled ram booster or free memory. What they seem to do is allocate large amount of memory say 1gb and then free it.

OS will either swap out the processes or cleanup inactive RAM (as is called in macos) and cached processes (in android).

My personal experience is calling purge command to freeup inactive memory does make stuckup apps run (case where available memory is few mbs and inactive memory is more than 100mb)

The same logic should apply to java-android apps which are cached, though I didnt find a purge command there.

So is this good practise or bad ? From a OS perspective is this hack correct ? Pros Cons.

Comment: Close as off topic for SO but, as far as Android goes, these hacks are pointless and usually lead to reduced performance.  Android is perfectly capable of managing it's own memory usage and does so efficiently and silently.

Comment: How to benchmark it. Technically (theoretically) you are correct, thats the reason I asked this question on SO. But the humungous number of these apps being sold did point to a fact that users are in someway  experiencing better responsiveness.

Comment: Nope.  It's like task killers.  Many users have not been able to understand the difference between desktop apps and mobile apps.  Without an exit button, and the perception that RAM needs to be kept free, they believe that apps are not performing.  There is plenty of empirical evidence out there on the web and my own experience tells me that "memory boosters" and task killers lead to reduced performance, especially battery.